# Basketball Rule: Reach in with contact but get ball first

Tags: rules, basketball

I've never really played in official basketball leagues with refs, only pickup games really. I come from a very heavy soccer background where if I get ball first then the players body its a legal tackle.

Something came up where I went in for a steal and got the ball first as he was making a move to his right and he ran through my arm after then. My understanding with a contact foul is if the ball isn't in the players hand and I make contact with the ball first the body contact isn't a foul.

Thanks

Comment: Your understanding of the football tackle laws aren't ideal either. "Got the ball first" is almost never sufficient reason for a tackle to be considered okay (despite what many players and officials think). It's the *absence* of a sufficient condition to *give* redress for an action, **not** the presence of a reason to withhold it, that matters.